# Integrate the Play Integrity API in Google play console

Tags: flutter, google-play-console, google-play-integrity-api

I am new to making apps live in Play console, I have an app that uses firebase phone auth. to remove recaptcha i need to enable app integrity API in cloud console that i did already then in play console i linked my app with my google cloud project and added

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.3.0'
```

in my build.gradle as well now the main issue I am having is this 3rd step on setting up play integrity api in Play console.

[image]

"Integrate the play Integrity API" and "Integrate Integrity API" both take me to documentation which I am not able to understand properly what to do and complete this step. I tried all the things they suggested me to do so, but still this step in incomplete. Btw I am using Phone auth in flutter app. is there something that i need to do it code to complete it?